# Creating new gsettings/dconf schemas

Tags: linux, dconf, gsettings

I would like to know how to go about creating new schema entries for  gsettings or dconf, to create an entirely new entity that does not exist.

ie; `/org/gnome/my-schema-entry/property-entry boolean 'foo-bar'`

When I went to look up some answers from Google it said I should do like this;

```
gsettings set org.gnome.my-schema-entry.property-entry:/org/gnome/my-schema-entry/property-entry boolean 'foo-bar'
```

but this just returns an error saying;

`No such schema 'org.gnome.my-schema-entry.property-entry'`

How do I even create or write a new schema entry that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish, more specifically ? Start [here](https://developer.gnome.org/GSettings/), see also GIO [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html) and _Sneetsher_'s answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/417330)

Comment: @don_crissti to learn more about how applications create entries for themselves to be added to the system to provide a new function or addon a feature to something else from a developers perspective.

Comment: In that case I think the docs I linked to would be a good starting point.

Comment: Hi! I want to add a new key to existing schema to enhance an application. Have you found in docs the answer to your question about new schemas? Can you help me to quickly add new key ? TIA